# How to open programmatically a lightbox popup in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, lightbox

I have a javascript function called from Joomla 2.5 that, when executed, must show a lightbox popup.

How can i show the message in popup programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

A good way I guess is to find out how the function is called, so call it again from your part.

For a pure programatic staff you can use other lightbox lib and integrate it in joomla. Like:

[Lightbox 1](http://fancybox.net/)

[Lightbox 2](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

There is a joomla module too for this kind of purpose. I didn't try any of these, I just suggest.

[Joomla module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-display/13816)